# Progressbar do not gone in webview

Tags: android, webview, navigation-drawer, android-progressbar

I am just implemented webview in navigation drawer.i am try to implement progressbar in following code but can't figure out how to  do it in following code. i read android docs and other question regarding webview and progressbar that does not help me.

```java
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        WebView WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        WebView Webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

if (myWebView.getProgress()>=100){
    setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
else{
    setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
}
```

I am new in android programming

Comment: you missed one closing bracket `}` for the if!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine to show a preloader

Main Activity

```
package com.android_examples.com.webviewprogressbarload;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

 WebView webview;
 ProgressBar pbar;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    pbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
 }

 public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient
 {
   @Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
   {

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
   {

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     view.loadUrl(url);
     return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
  {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     super.onPageFinished(view, url);
     pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
```

}
}

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.android_examples.com.webviewprogressbarload.MainActivity" >

 <ProgressBar
 android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 <WebView
 android:id="@+id/webView1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I just implemented webview in if else loop in navigation drawer . but can't figure out how to implement progressbar in if else loop. thanks for answer!!

Comment: If..else and loops are two different things. If you can post your code, that will help you answer it better.

Comment: In if else i just implemented webview and its work fine but i can't find any code for progressbar in if else.

Comment: It's always better to post your code so that people around here can help you  better identify and solve your problem.

Comment: Can you help now?